# Send raw ZPL data over Google cloud print

Tags: java, printing, zpl, google-cloud-print

Is it possible to send RAW ZPL data from GCP to a wireless printer?
When i try following the GCP documentation, i see that the print job is added but the print never goes through(for raw ZPL data).

I'm able to successfully print a PDF over GCP to a regular printer(non ZPL printer).
I'm using Google chrome predominantly for my tests.

Has anyone had success printing raw ZPL data over GCP?

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Comment: Also looking into this.  Looks like you can do this with other services like https://www.printnode.com/docs/api/curl/#printjobs

Comment: I tried to use printnode, did not work for me. Support wan't great either. I ended up using a third party app to trigger the print to a zebra printer.

Comment: @user1751510 can you tell me which app you've used?

Comment: I have no affiliation with printnode, but this is just to say that I settled on using those guys. The service works, but installation is kind of off-putting - esp. if the end users are your customer.